# ruby of support in vim on windows

Tags: ruby, windows, vim

I am new to vim and would like to configure command-t plugin to work in vim 7.3. It says it doesn't have ruby support. Is there any way to configure vim to have ruby support on windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to compile vim with `--enable-rubyinterp` flag.
Check if vim has support for ruby using `:version` in vi.

If that shows `-ruby` (no ruby support) then you will have to compile from vim source or fetch an installer which was compiled that way.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your problem is that you do not have ruby installed and that plug-in need it. Try installing ruby:

http://rubyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure vim to have ruby support (as in checking a box or changing an option). You have to download a distribution of vim with ruby support or download the sources and compile it yourself. Type

```
vim --version
```

If it says "-ruby" then you need to install a different vim version that has it supported (+ruby).

You can follow the step-by-step here: [My own post](http://rubyrookie.wordpress.com/2012/09/01/command-t-installation-on-windows/) or [Official doc installation](https://wincent.com/products/command-t)